# Why is the output 0 in one but the correct answer in the other?

Tags: c, area

Suppose you have to find the area of a triangle when base and height are given

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    float base,height,area;
    printf("Enter base and height of triangle: \n");
    scanf("%f%f",&base,&height);
    area=0.5*base*height;
    printf("The area of the triangle is %f",area);
    return 0;
}
```

How come the program gives the right answer with the above code but not with the one below??

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    float base,height,area;
    printf("Enter base and height of triangle: \n");
    scanf("%f%f",&base,&height);
    area=(1/2)*base*height;
    printf("The area of the triangle is %f",area);
    return 0;
}
```

This one shows 0 regardless of what values you input. What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: The second one computes 1/2 as integer, which is always 0.

Comment: In C, "/" operator returns only the integer part of the division, hence the formula for the area becomes 0 * base * height.

Comment: try something like `1.0f/2` or `1/2.0f` to tell the compiler you want floating point division there.

Comment: Neither is correct. Binary `*` has left-to-right associativity so in case of `0.5*base*height` the whole expression will be evaluated as `double`.

Comment: @kmalarski trying to typecast it wont work either?

Comment: @Lundin sorry, I don't know what that means, could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: It means that if you use `float` types you should always use floating point constants ending with an `f`. That is: `0.5f`. Otherwise you might as well use `double` everywhere (which is probably the correct choice anyway, if programming for a PC).

Comment: @Lundin ahh alright, thank you for explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

`(1/2)`

divides two integers. In contrary to python or several other languages, this won't be implicitly cast to a float, but stays as integer. Hence, the result is 0.

Changing the expression to

```
(1./2)
```

solves your problem.